# sticky menu gets stuck and conflicts with google maps api

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, google-chrome

The page has sticky menu on top and the Google map loaded in the content(mid of the page).. When the page scrolls down, menu becomes sticky and when it gets close to the Google map, the menu gets stuck mid page instead of sticking to the top of the window. This is the issue which only occurs in chrome..

Thanks

This is the link. It only glitches out on chrome. https://www.fornobravo.com/how-to-buy/find-a-dealer

[image]

Comment: Provide us some code.

Comment: This is a the link. It only glitches out on chrome. https://www.fornobravo.com/how-to-buy/find-a-dealer/

Comment: The menu works fine for me. 
Which chrome version are you using ? 
Also check that maybe an extension is causing this.

Comment: Really? Everyone else that tries it, it breaks for them too Currently I'm running 43.0.2357.134 of chrome. Try scrolling all the way to the bottom of the page, then stop scrolling, then scroll back up. It should get stuck or once you hit the map, you can't even see it. I also have no extensions on my chrome.

Comment: Works fine still. 
If you can create a fiddle for this, that would be great. 
Also you sure don't have any errors in the console right ?

Comment: No errors in the console. I can try to create a fiddle, I don't know if I can recreate this. What version of chrome are you using? btw, I appreciate you looking into this.

Comment: I have the same chrome 43.0.2357.134. 
Could you post a screenshot of what happens ?

Comment: I edited my post, and added an image.

Comment: I really cant replicate the issue. 
Did you try to inspect element and see why does it not remain fixed ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83573/discussion-between-ankur-anand-and-dgas02).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding to the top of my function top: 1px and at the bottom of my function top: 0.

```
var sticky_navigation = function(){
    jQuery('.hmainmenu').css('top', '1px');

    var scroll_top = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) {
        jQuery('.hmainmenu').addClass('fixedMainMenu');
        jQuery('.hmainmenu').children('a').addClass('showmenubuttons');
    } else {
        jQuery('.hmainmenu').removeClass('fixedMainMenu');
        jQuery('.hmainmenu').children('a').removeClass('showmenubuttons');
    }

    jQuery('.hmainmenu').css('top', '0');
};
```